# How to show <p> tag in <ul> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a `<ul>` tag that contain 2 `<li>` tag with a `<p>` tag that contain text:

```
<ul>
    <li>List-item-1<p>para-1</p></li>
    <li>List-item-2<p>para-2</p></li>
</ul>
```

I want to remove `List-item-1` and `List-item-2` from the code. I tried this:

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $('li').html($('p'));
});
```

But I am getting **output** as below:

- para-1

para-2

para-1

para-2

- para-1

para-2

para-1

para-2

How do I get output with `<p>` tag only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `find()` function here.

```js
$('ul li').html(function(){
  return $(this).find('p');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <li>List-item-1<p>para-1</p></li>
    <li>List-item-2<p>para-2</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `innerText` even without jQuery.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(li => {
  li.innerText = li.querySelector('p').innerText
})
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>List-item-1<p>para-1</p></li>
    <li>List-item-2<p>para-2</p></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove the text.

```js
$('ul li').each((i,ele) => {
  ele.firstChild.remove()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>List-item-1
    <p>para-1</p>
  </li>
  <li>List-item-2
    <p>para-2</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```